# MariaDB connect to a DSN in odbc.ini

Tags: java, odbc, mariadb, dsn, isql

I am trying to connect from Java to a DSN using MariaDB,

If I not use the DSN it works

```
Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://< host >:<port>/< database >", < user >,< password >);
```

But I would like that mariadb uses the host and port specified in the odbc.ini, but I can’t make it work.

I have tried many ways but it did not work, I could not find anything on internet about it.

eg:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb:< DSN_NAME >", < user >,< password >);
```

The DSN is correctly configured in the odbc.ini, it works with isql

Can anyone help me?,

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/207385-java-to-mysql-connection-using-the-jdbc-odbc-bridge/